# dynamic routes in nextjs crawlable to search engines?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

I am working on NextJS movie application to learn NextJS. Homepage contains movie name and little description. After clicking on the movie it takes user to the specific page where it displays additional information. That data is coming from database.

I just wanted to know are these dynamic pages crawlable to search engines. For example user is searching for Forrest Gump on google/bing and my dyamic route contains that data. Google/bing is going to crawl that data or not?

Comment: Of course, that will be crawled if that data is present in view-source. To view view-source do ctrl+u on chrome. There search for `Forrest Gump` on that page. If `Forrest Gump` is available there then google will crawl that data.

Answer (score 1):

If each movie page is rendered using SSR ( or if it contains preview data) it will be crawled by google / Bing.

If you don't want it to be crawled, you can use meta tag like

```
<meta name=”robots” content=”noindex, follow”>
```